# Flipping biased coin and stopping on the $7^{th}$ trial after $3$ consecutive tosses (H or T)

Tags: combinatorics

The question states:

`A biased coin with probability p, $0 < p < 1$, of success (heads) is tossed
until for the first time, the same result occurs three times in succession
(that is, three heads or three tails in succession).
Find the probability that the game will end at the seventh throw.`

Here is my work: just looking to see if this is correct.
So the sample space, assuming we end with the last 3H (by symmetry we can calculate the last 3T) includes $\{HTH-THHH, HHT-THHH,TTH-THHH,THH-THHH,THT-THHH \}$

The last 4 throws must be THHH to stop the game on the 7th toss.
My original answer was $\frac{2 *5}{2^7}$.However after Lulu comment brought to my attention that I was not taking into account the probability p.  So I edited my answer to the below result.

Final Answer:  here I use the sample space previously defined to include the probability p.
so is the probability of ending the game on the 7th throw = $3p^5(1-p)^2+2(1-p)^3p^4+3(1-p)^5p^2+2p^3(1-p)^4$

Comment: You are neglecting the fact that the coin is biased (your answer doesn't even depend on $p$, for example). This makes it harder to casually invoke symmetry.  But, you have basically listed all the winning paths so you can just compute by hand.

Comment: If you edit the question in a manner that invalidates a comment or an existing answer, please indicate this (e.g. by responding to the comment or by marking the edit as an edit/update). Otherwise the result is a) confusing and b) unfair towards the commenter, as it will appear as if their comment wasn't valid.

Comment: thank you very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you give in the edited question is correct. [Here's a graph of it.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%203p%5E5(1-p)%5E2%2B2(1-p)%5E3p%5E4%2B3(1-p)%5E5p%5E2%2B2p%5E3(1-p)%5E4%20for%20p%3D0..1&dataset=)